# My Kid died with diamond armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

In Minecraft Comes Alive (MCA) you can have your children equip armor. However my son died and he had diamond armor. Of course it's probably gone now but could I have gotten it?

If I found my son's body could I have gotten the diamond armor back?

Answer (score -1):

Of course!
If you die, you have a time limit of 5 minutes, then the items vanish.
It's a well used game mechnaic for making timers with pressure plates for automated farms.
Also, it would lay there longer if the chunk is unloaded. The 5 minutes rule only takes time off when the chunk is loaded.

Except lava; it kills items and fire does, too.

Comment: This is not about the player dying, but some specific NPC. Does this also drop his items.

Comment: to arperum yes, also you have to add to the 5 time limit of item despawning that it only counts if the items are loaded. that means that it has to be in loaded chuncks (the area around you like 256 blocks depending on your render distance)